# Is a weak_ptr to object X still valid during object X's destruction

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I have something akin to the following:

```
class A {
  std::weak_ptr<B> r;
  A (std::weak_ptr<B> x) : r(x) {}

  ~A() {
    r.lock();
  }
};


class B : std::enable_shared_from_this<B> {
  std::shared_ptr<A> r;
  foo() {
    r = std::make_shared<A>(shared_from_this());
  }
};
```

During the destruction of B, ~A() is called; but it wants to call back into the object being destructed.
Ignoring design issues around this, is the behaviour defined, or is it compiler dependant?

Comment: Could you provide a usage sample ? a question is : an instance of A named a gets an instance of B b and b holds a weak ref to the same a ?

Comment: Order of destruction is done in reverse order of construction, so `B` is still *'valid'*, but accessing members after `r` would be UB.

Comment: @tobi303 sorry - quite right; question updated

Comment: @Theforgotten  correct, an instance of B is holding an A that holds a weak reference to that B.

Comment: If it is the destruction of `r` that invokes the destructor of `B` then the destructor body of `A` has already finished. The storagre is still there, so you could obtain a pointer to it, but you can't use it in any way.

Comment: And I'm not even certain that locking the weak pointer is guaranteed to obtain anything. When does that shared pointer decrement the shared ref-count?

Comment: "And I'm not even certain that locking the weak pointer is guaranteed to obtain anything" - me neither, hence the question :)

Comment: You may want to clarify that. To me, as written, you seem to ask if you can safely use the `A` pointer you got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the expression r.lock() will fail (i.e. return an empty shared_ptr).

The weak_ptr is valid, but the shared_ptr is already destructing the B.

the sequence of events will be:

```
shared_ptr<B>::~shared_ptr()
 <strong reference count reduced to 0, destruction process begins>
 <shared_ptr<B> is now empty>
  ~B()
   shared_ptr<A>::~shared_ptr()
    ~A()
     weak_ptr<B>::lock -> returns shared_ptr<B>(nullptr)
```

There is a strong smell of suboptimal design here. Might be a good idea to formally write out the requirements.